# Configuring Ehcache - CacheManager must not be null

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I tried to configure EhCache programmatically, but I have some problems... Firstly, I tried to use the newest version, where I just created config class with just one method and then I get the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilderSpec`.

I tried with lower version, which is 2.10.4, which is already in Spring Boot, but now I'm getting an error that `CacheManager must not be null` and I have no idea what is the problem... Probably I'm missing something, but I don't know what...

**Current code with Ehcache 2.X:**

```
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheResolver;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleCacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleCacheResolver;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class EhCacheConfiguration implements CachingConfigurer {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setName("myCacheName");
        cacheConfiguration.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");
        cacheConfiguration.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(1000);

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(cacheConfiguration);

        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new SimpleCacheResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new SimpleCacheErrorHandler();
    } 
}
```

**Previous version of code with Ehcache 3.X:**

```
import static org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder;
import static org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder;
import static org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.ehcache.CacheManager;
import org.ehcache.config.units.EntryUnit;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;
import org.ehcache.expiry.Duration;
import org.ehcache.expiry.Expirations;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class EhCacheConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EhCacheConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        log.info("Creating cache manager programmatically");

        try (CacheManager cacheManager = newCacheManagerBuilder()
                .withCache("sessionCache",
                        newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Long.class, String.class,
                                newResourcePoolsBuilder().heap(2000, EntryUnit.ENTRIES).offheap(1, MemoryUnit.GB))
                                        .withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)))
                                        .withExpiry(Expirations.timeToIdleExpiration(Duration.of(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))))
                .build(true)) {

            return cacheManager;
        }
    }
```

The class is in the subpackage of package where is the MyApplication class.

**MyApplication class:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application is using Spring Boot and is running on WebLogic server...

Edit:

Added `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.app.lui.serviceweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>lui-serviceWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>lui-serviceWeb</name>
    <description>Lui Project</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.app.lui.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>lui-drools</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache CXF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>lui-serviceWeb</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Added project:

[Ehcache project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ck86lz6vk680n66/lui.zip?dl=0)

Logs:

[Ehcache 2.X stack trace](https://pastebin.com/1dAP8v82)

[Ehcache 3.X stack trace](https://pastebin.com/sewbKwq6)

Comment: What version of spring boot are you using? Can you share what spring boot dependencies you are including in your `pom.xml` / `build.gradle`

Comment: @Ben check updated question.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the stack trace you get when you're using the ehcache 3+? I'm curious as to from where it's trying to load com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilderSpec? Please provide the full stack trace, and any of your code that is referenced by said stack trace.

Comment: @Ben Updated! Logs and project.

Answer (score 0):

You need the cacheResolver to know the cacheManager.

So, in your current code, just replace the cacheResolver bean with:

```
@Bean
@Override
public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
  return new SimpleCacheResolver(cacheManager());
}
```

And it is done. Might be the same for EhCache 3.X but I didn't test it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

We will need a fully working project to answer wit certainty. Right now, I tried your code and had to hack around to make it compile. `CacheBuilderSpec` is indeed a guava thing. So it seems Spring is picking Guava as its cache implementation, not Ehcache.

You might want to debug `CacheAutoConfiguration` and `GuavaCacheConfiguration`. The latter will be initialized at some point by Spring.

Comment: Check my update in the question. You will find everything there :)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are not running spring boot main `LuiApplication`? That the error only occurs when deploying on weblogic.

Comment: That's the thing. It has to be deployed on weblogic... And errors appears during the deployment... And in this demo project, which reproduce the error are only two classes...

Comment: But launching the main class `LuiApplication` doesn't show the problem no?

Comment: If by launching you mean deployment without Ehcache configuration class, then yes there is no errors. When I'm deploying with Ehcache then it throws errors. When without then everything is fine and working properly.

Comment: No. I mean, instead of deploying the war in weblogic, just launching `LuiApplication.main`

Comment: I've just tested it and running `LuiApplication.main` as a Java Application also throws the same errors.

Comment: this should be a comment because it doesn't answer OP's question